# Making a dynamic sizing table lock it's size when window enlarged

Tags: html, css

I have a dynamically resizing table for small browser windows. It resizes great! It looks great under 810px, but the problem is that I want it to lock the size of the table once its over 800px. Right now when I get over 810px, I lose the Arial font and the border-collapse. I don't know why this isn't working!

Please take a look and see if a new set of eyes can spot what's going on.

```css
 #formatscreen {
  font-family: Arial;
  width: 800px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  //    padding-left: 5px;
  //    padding-right: 5px;

}
#screen_symbol {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block
}
#screen_price {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block
}
#screen_net_pct {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block
}
#screen_expiry.header,
#screen_type.header,
#screen_dist.header,
#screen_short_leg.header,
#screen_long_leg.header {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block
}
#screen_change.header,
#screen_delta.header,
#screen_short_leg_vol.header,
#screen_long_leg_vol.header,
#screen_net.header {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-block
}
#screen_expiry,
#screen_type,
#screen_dist,
#screen_short_leg,
#screen_long_leg {
  font-size: 24px;
  display: inline-block
}
#screen_change,
#screen_delta,
#screen_short_leg_vol,
#screen_long_leg_vol,
#screen_net {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px),
(max-width: 810px) {
  #formatscreen {
    font-family: Arial;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  th {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2.5vw;
  }
  th,
  td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
    //  padding-left: 5px;
    //  padding-right: 5px;

  }
  #screen_symbol {
    font-size: 5vw;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block
  }
  #screen_price {
    font-size: 4vw;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block
  }
  #screen_net_pct {
    font-size: 3vw;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block
  }
  #screen_expiry.header,
  #screen_type.header,
  #screen_dist.header,
  #screen_short_leg.header,
  #screen_long_leg.header {
    font-size: 2.5vw;
    display: inline-block
  }
  #screen_change.header,
  #screen_delta.header,
  #screen_short_leg_vol.header,
  #screen_long_leg_vol.header,
  #screen_net.header {
    font-size: 1.75vw;
    display: inline-block
  }
  #screen_expiry,
  #screen_type,
  #screen_dist,
  #screen_short_leg,
  #screen_long_leg {
    font-size: 3vw;
    display: inline-block
  }
  #screen_change,
  #screen_delta,
  #screen_short_leg_vol,
  #screen_long_leg_vol,
  #screen_net {
    font-size: 2vw;
    display: inline-block
  }
}
#screen_change.up {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
#screen_change.down {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
.right {
  text-align: right;
}
tr[data-bau="Bull Put"] {
  background: #99ff99;
}
tr[data-bau="Bear Call"] {
  background: #ff9999;
}
tr:hover[data-bau="Bull Put"] {
  background-color: #00b300;
  cursor: pointer;
}
tr:hover[data-bau="Bear Call"] {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="prescreen">
  <table id="formatscreen">
    <tr>
      <th>
        Symbol</th>
      <th>Price Action</th>
      <th>Expiry Date
        <br>Type</th>
      <th class="right">
        <div id="screen_dist" class="header">Distance</div>
        <div id="screen_delta" class="header">Delta</div>
      </th>
      <th class="right">
        <div id="screen_short_leg" class="header">Short Leg</div>

        <div id="screen_short_leg_vol" class="header">Volume</div>
      </th>
      <th class="right">
        <div id="screen_long_leg" class="header">Long Leg</div>
        <div id="screen_long_leg_vol" class="header">Volume</div>
      </th>
      <th>Return</th>
    </tr>
    <tr data-bau="Bull Put">
      <td>
        <div id="screen_symbol">IBB</div>
      </td>
      <td class="center">
        <div id="screen_price">$1260.39</div>
        <div id="screen_change" class="down">-$12.36 (0.91%)</div>
      </td>
      <td class="center">
        <div id="screen_expiry">20160819</div>
        <div id="screen_type">Bull Put</div>
      </td>
      <td class="right">
        <div id="screen_dist">15.5%</div>
        <div id="screen_delta">0.077</div>
      </td>
      <td class="right">
        <div id="screen_short_leg">$1220.00</div>
        <div id="screen_short_leg_vol">1420</div>
      </td>
      <td class="right">
        <div id="screen_long_leg">$1915.00</div>
        <div id="screen_short_leg_vol">20</div>
      </td>
      <td class="right">
        <div id="screen_net_pct">3.00%</div>
        <div id="screen_net">$0.25</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-bau="Bear Call">
      <td>
        <div id="screen_symbol">NFLX</div>
      </td>
      <td class="center">
        <div id="screen_price">$1260.39</div>
        <div id="screen_change" class="up">+$12.36 (0.91%)</div>
      </td>
      <td class="center">
        <div id="screen_expiry">20160819</div>
        <div id="screen_type">Bull Put</div>
      </td>
      <td class="right">
        <div id="screen_dist">15.5%</div>
        <div id="screen_delta">0.077</div>
      </td>
      <td class="right">
        <div id="screen_short_leg">$1220.00</div>
        <div id="screen_short_leg_vol">20</div>
      </td>
      <td class="right">
        <div id="screen_long_leg">$1915.00</div>
        <div id="screen_short_leg_vol">20</div>
      </td>
      <td class="right">
        <div id="screen_net_pct">3.00%</div>
        <div id="screen_net">$0.25</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  words words
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, wrong fiddle. This is the one: https://jsfiddle.net/wolfpack06/3g0brrbw/1/

Answer (score 0):

All you need here is one simple CSS property: `max-width`

```
#formatscreen {
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: I've tried that, it doesn't seem to work how I want it to. I want the table to be 100% width if less than 800px. Latest fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wolfpack06/3g0brrbw/1/

Comment: @Alex: Please add your code in a snippet in the original answer, or describe your problem, as I can't view jsfiddles, nor will it be referenceable indefinitely for future visitors. That being said, if your actual table is different than the one you posted in here, there's a possibility that the content itself forces the table to be wider than the 800px you describe.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `vw` for font sizes. Size of `vw` changes according to the device width.

Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/LtLmr5s5/1/

Comment: Sorry, wrong fiddle. This is the one: https://jsfiddle.net/wolfpack06/3g0brrbw/1/

Comment: @Alex  Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/LtLmr5s5/1/
Just changed all `vw` to `px`.

Comment: Thanks! I think I have it figured out. I need to keep using vw, otherwise on a mobile or smaller screen, the font won't resize to proportionally fit the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine if you remove the in CSS not allowed `//` comments:

```
//@ width:800px
//2.5vw = 20px
//1.75vw = 14px
//1vw = 8px
```

They can be used in SCSS only.

So this is enough:

```
#formatscreen {
  font-family: Arial;
  width: 800px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

/* ... */

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px),
(max-width:810px) {
  #formatscreen {
    width: 100%;
  }
  /* ... */
}
/* ... */
```

Furthermore there is no need to set a media query for this as you can see in [TheThirdMans answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38239374/making-a-dynamic-sizing-table-lock-its-size-when-window-enlarged#answer-38239475).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I have it fixed now! I kept the @media because I want it to resize the font using vh when the screen is in mobile or smaller than ~800px. Does that make sense?